# Hinting votes for CW contributions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, community-wiki, voting

I would like to learn about opinions about visually indicating votes for contributions to community wiki; what I have in mind is something analogous to the green button in the "menue-line" for upvotes for contributions to "ordinary" questions and the red or green entries in the achievements list.
Maybe a gray button might be used to indicate upvotes to CW and gray textcolor for the achievements list.

I kindly ask for focusing on discussing the suggested feature and not so much on how it might be made available.

Comment: I think that what you're asking for is notifications when someone upvotes a community wiki answer which you contributed to. Is that correct?

Comment: It's a bit unclear (at least to me) what is actually asked here. But maybe it is still useful to point out some older posts on [meta.se] which seem related: [Votes to community wiki posts aren't visible in reputation history if there are no "real" reputation events that day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349893), [Tracking of Community Wiki upvotes and Comment Upvotes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1403), [Add votes on my CW posts to my summary screen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/42531), etc.